# ¿Cómo se llaman las funciones `...nombre` y `entero%entero` en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo duda sobre cómo es que se llaman dichas funciones, ya que he estado buscando y no encuentro información referente, también quisiera saber en qué cosas me serían útiles además de saber cómo se llaman.
Ejemplo `...arreglo` :

```js
mi_funcion('uno','dos','tres','cuatro','cinco','seis','siete','ocho','nueve','diez');

     function mi_funcion(...arreglo){
        for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
          console.log(arreglo[i]);
        }
     }
```

Como ven, el `...arreglo` me recibe los parámetros y lo convierte en un array para después listarlos.
Ahora el `entero%entero`, ejemplo:

```js
mi_funcion2();

     function mi_funcion2(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          console.log(i%5);
        }
     }
```

Aquí lo que hace es que el número de la izquierda comenzará a contar desde el 0 hasta el numero que se le indicó en la posición derecha, y cuando se cumplen los 5, el de la izquierda vuelve a iniciar desde el 0 y así sucesivamente.
Espero que alguien me resuelva mis dudas sobre dichas funciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Cuando tienes tres puntos se llaman [Parametros Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest)**

Como tu mencionas toma  el argumento y lo trata como un arreglo.

Otra manera en que se usa es para tomar las propiedades de un objeto (lo siguiente no aplica a arreglos, solo a objetos). Aquí se pueden hacer dos cosas:

Tomar el 'resto' de las propiedades de otro objeto en uno nuevo:

```js
var objOrig = {
  quien: 'Pablito',
  accion: 'clavó',
  que: 'un clavito',
  donde: 'en la cabeza de un calvito'
}

var objNuevo = {
  ...objOrig, // "Desarmo" objNuevo para meterlo aquí.
  tipoDeClavo: 'pequeño'
}
console.log(objOrig);
console.log(objNuevo);

// Ten cuidado porque el orden cuenta.
// Lo último es lo que vale y puedes anular algun valor del objeto en el que se hace rest

var otroObj = {
  ...objNuevo,
  quien: 'Pedrito' // Vamos a anular quien
}
console.log(otroObj);
```

Tomar las propiedades de un objeto y desarmarlo, el resto de las propiedades que no se tomaron va a a la variable que hace rest

```js
var yo = {
  nombre: 'Nery Ortez',
  idUsuario: 'adba5415dg121s4s6a',
  pais: 'Honduras',
  profesion: 'Procrastinador',
  tiempoExperiencia: '4 años'
}
// Extraemos variables que necesitamos de yo
// Y el resto lo dejamos en otra variable por si acaso
var {idUsuario, nombre, pais, ...loQueSobra} = yo;
// Notá el uso de los tres puntos
console.log(idUsuario);
console.log(loQueSobra);
```

### En `entero%entero` el `%` es "módulo"

Es una operacion matematica y el resultado es el residuo de la division entre los dos numeros.

Osea, va a dividir los dos enteros y te va a devolver lo que sobra de la división. En tu ejemplo lo que hace es devolver el residuo de todos los numeros del cero al nueve entre cinco.

Otro ejemplo muy usado es para saber si un numero es par o impar. Lo que haces es hacer modulo con dos y si el resultado es cero es para, si es uno es impar.

```js
mi_funcion2();

function mi_funcion2(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var r = i%2;
    // Todo numero impar divido entre dos da como residuo "1"
    console.log(r); 
    // console.log(i + " es " + (r===1 ? "impar" : "par") );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Los tres puntos es el operador *rest* y el operador `%` es el operador matemático *módulo* o resto:

### El Operador rest

Tu ejemplo es el más típico, [agrupando los parámetros que recibe una función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/parametros_rest):

```
function test(a, b, ...opcionales) {
  //..
}
```

[Pero también te permite otras cosas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread), como las siguientes trabajando con arrays:

```js
const array1=[1,2]
const arrayA=['a','b']

//concatenar arrays y otros elementos
const union=[
  ...array1,
  'otra cosa',
  /*valor undefined, al dejar un hueco*/,
  ...arrayA];

console.log(union)


//copiar un array sin usar slice

const copia=[...array1];

console.log('Copia de array1',copia);
console.log(array1 === copia);
```

Pero también con objetos:

```js
const obj1={
  atributo1: 'a'
};
const obj2={
  atributo2: 'b'
};


//mezcla
const mezcla = {
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2,
  atributo3: 'c'
};

console.log(mezcla);
```

### El operador módulo o resto

Sencillamente hace la división y se queda con el resto entero de la misma:

```js
console.log('10 entre 3 tiene de resto',10%3);
```

Puede ser útil para (por ejemplo) recorrer una matriz usando un único bucle o para realizar varias pasadas sobre una estructura, reiniciando los índices:

```js
const m=[
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
];

let suma=0;
for (let i=0;i<9;i++) {
  let x = i%3;
  let y = Math.floor(i/3);
  debugger;
  suma += m[y][x];
}

console.log('la suma de la matriz es',suma)
```